# How can I update the DOM after Ajax Call (jQuery)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I update the DOM with new record added element after call?

Should I return the newly inserted db record contents on call back then append using jquery?

Please advice if not enough data to answer question.

```
$(function(){

        $('#postentry').submit(function() {
          var tyu = $('#tittle_ent').val();
          if(tyu.length <= 2)
            {alert('Enter More Text!'); return false;}else
            {
                $.post(  
                 "posts_in.php",  
                 $("#postentry").serialize(),  
                    function(data){  
                        //alert(data); 
                    }  
                );  
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
```

Each record look like this:

```
<div id="post349" class="myclass">
This is some text.    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.post()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'posts_in.php',
    data: $("#postentry").serialize(),
    success:function(data){
        var id='post349';
        $('<div></div>').attr('id',id).addClass('myclass').html(data).appendTo('#records_wrapper');
    }
});
```

Quick demo of how the div will be appended and populated: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/zuPA2/1/

Comment: How can I return the id of the newly added record for insertion as well?

Comment: You'd want to return a JSON object from your posts_in.php page, something like this: `echo json_encode('{"id":"post349","record":"This is some text"}');`. Then in your ajax `success:function()`, you could reference the object as `data.id` and `data.record`. You'd also want to add `dataType:'json'` to your ajax parameters so JQuery will know how to parse the incoming data.

Comment: maybe its silly question but when you goes for "view source" it wont show changed code. So it is gonna be SEO friendly ?

Comment: @AlienWebguy I don't really know how content.php should look like. I did see that post some time ago...

Answer (score 1):

You can either return a complete record in the surrounding `div` from php or you can just get the newly inserted ID and build the record in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(  
     "posts_in.php",  
     $("#postentry").serialize(),  
        function(data){  
            $('#myDivOnThePage').append(data);
        }  
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If data contains new record, so yes, parse it and append where and like you want.

By creating a new jsfiddle.net with an example, I can help you a little bit more...

Answer (score 0):

In your JS file you could write this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: posts_in.php,
    data: {
       action: 'updateDomAfterAjaxCall',
       post_id: postentry
   },

   success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

       var linkid = '#' + postentry;
       jQuery(linkid).html('');
       jQuery(linkid).append(data);

   },
   error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert(errorThrown);
   }
 });
```

In your backend code, you could do this. In this case, I used PHP.

```
 function updateDomAfterAjaxCall() {

    $post_ID = $_POST['post_id'];
    // Carefully tranverse the dom to 
    // Update records of the DOM that is 
    // affected by the new entry
    // so that it behave almost like
    // headless browser
    // Target footer-postentry
    // header-postentry, sidebar-postentry, content-postentry

    $result = '';
    $record_from_db = ""

    $results.='<div class="myclass" >'.$record_from_db.'</div>';
    die($result);
  }
```